# Can a scope in a has_many fully replace the default join?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a complicated join:

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories,
           ->(s) { where(/* A complex query */) },
           class_name: 'SubmissionFieldHistory'
end
```

I'd like that scope query to *replace* the default conditions that gets generated by ActiveRecord, however it seems to be *added* to the conditions.

Is there a simple way to say `has_many :histories, :but_join_it_how_i_say`?

Comment: What do you mean by "default conditions"? Can you add some examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumption:

If by "default conditions", you meant the default SQL condition `WHERE HISTORIES_TABLE.submission_id = SOME_SUBMISSION_ID`.

### Solution 1:

To specify a custom query for `has_many`, use [`unscope`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/unscope):

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories,
    ->(s) { unscope(:where).where(/* A complex query */) },
    class_name: 'SubmissionFieldHistory'
end
```

*`unscope(:where)` above will remove any/all prior `WHERE` SQL queries in the chain, of which one of them includes the default `WHERE HISTORIES_TABLE.submission_id = SOME_SUBMISSION_ID`, of which is what you want to remove.*

#### Usage:

```
submission = Submission.find(1)
submission.histories
# SubmissionFieldHistory Load (5.5ms)  SELECT  "submission_field_histories".* FROM "submission_field_histories"
#   WHERE /* A complex query */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

### Solution 2:

However, because  `unscope(:where)` removes all prior `WHERE` conditions, it also then removes the condition supplied by `default_scope` (if you have a `default_scope` inside the `SubmissionFieldHistory`). In order to also make it work for `default_scope`, you can use the more specific `unscope(where: SOME_ATTRIBUTE)` instead like below:

**app/models/submission_field_history.rb**

```
class SubmissionFieldHistory < ApplicationRecord
  # example: (default to not fetching anymore "deleted" records)
  default_scope { where(is_deleted: false) }

  belongs_to :submission
end
```

**app/models/submission.rb**

```
class Submission < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :histories,
    ->(s) { unscope(where: :submission_id).where(/* A complex query */) },
    class_name: 'SubmissionFieldHistory'
```

#### Usage:

```
submission = Submission.find(1)
submission.histories
# SubmissionFieldHistory Load (5.5ms)  SELECT "submission_field_histories".* FROM "submission_field_histories"
#   WHERE "submission_field_histories".is_deleted = false
#   AND /* A complex query */ LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Comment: Thank you! `unscope` is exactly what I needed.